# Javascript: How to get current object value in an associative array?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
    "key": "some",
    "foo": function() {return obj.key; // key undefined}
}
```

is there a way to get the reference to key inside the function?

Comment: What is it that you're ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: use 'this' instead of obj

Comment: question edited. I typed the error msg wrong. Sry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably. If `foo` is called as `obj.foo()`, you’ll be able to use `this.key`. However, `obj` should *not* be `undefined` at that point; if you’re changing it later and don’t want to rely on `this`, you can keep it in a different scope:

```
var obj = (function () {
    var obj = {
        key: "some",
        foo: function () { return obj.key; }
    };

    return obj;
})();
```

Comment: @NSF: There are only three possibilities: a) `obj` isn’t what you think it is; b) `obj.key` isn’t what you think it is; c) it’s not actually called `obj.key`. Could you provide a short example that reproduces the problem, please?

Comment: @minitech—given that the OP is global code, there is no need for a closure. Of course the OP may really want it to work in a function context, or *foo* might be assigned from an IIFE, but the OP hasn't asked for that. Yet. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: Originally, the question said `obj` was undefined; the IIFE stops it from being overwritten directly in the same scope.

Comment: @minitech Err... You're right. Obj happens to be changed above this line. Since this is only an excerpt of the code it doesn't reveal the problem. Also I basically made up this example so the actual problem is a bit more complex than this one. Thanks anyway.